# IIS Rewriting: Why it not returning fresh data

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I am using the following rewriting rule to get the data from the other server, and it is returning the result for the first time. But when I am updating/adding the data, my API is still returning the previous data(no updated data). But after approx 30 seconds when I again hit the API, It returns updated data.

It's working fine when I am using a direct URL(http://172.20.20.23:3000/).

I don't know what am I missing. Please help me to identify the issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>    
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Frontend Router" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" /> 
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                  <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(qosapi)" negate="true" /> 
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
         <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="^qosapi/(.*)" />                   
              <action type="Rewrite" url="http://172.20.20.23:3000/{R:1}" />
         </rule> 
      </rules>
       
    </rewrite>
  
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a reverse proxy caching issue. I just disabled the caching and it's working perfectly fine now.

See the below image:
[image: "IIS Manager"=>"Application Request Routing Cache"=>"Server Proxy Settings"]